# Automapper: Nested mapping with collection list inside

Tags: automapper

I have a collection of objects which needs to populate the collection in destination class. I have tried a few things but something is completely missing. Any help is highly appreciated.
Here is the source objects:

```
public class SourceClass
{
    public Sessions SourceSessions { get; set; }
}
public class Sessions
{
    public List<Session> SessionCollection { get; set; }
}

public class Session
{
    public DateTime SessionInfo { get; set; }
}
```

And the destination objects is :

```
 public class DestinationClass
{
    public List<DateTime> Sessions;
}
```

I need to populate the DestinationClass using AutoMapper. 
I see that the only possible mapping is going to take place between Session and DestinationClass where the actual mapping needs to happen, however, DestinationClass property is collection of whats inside Session but then in order to get the collection, i mapped it to Sessions object instead and tried to write a custom resolver like this:

```
public static class AutoMapperConfig
{
    public static void RegisterMappings()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Sessions, DestinationClass>();
    }
}
public class CustomResolver : ValueResolver<Sessions, DestinationClass>
{
    protected override DestinationClass ResolveCore(Sessions source)
    {
        DestinationClass dest = new DestinationClass();
        List<DateTime> lstDates = new List<DateTime>();
        foreach (Session session in source.SessionCollection)
            lstDates.Add(session.SessionInfo);

        dest.Sessions = lstDates;
        return dest;
    }
}
```

then executing it like below is not working. Can not understand what and where its wrong.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session session1 = new Session();
        session1.SessionInfo = DateTime.Now;

        Session session2 = new Session();
        session2.SessionInfo = DateTime.Now;

        Sessions sessions = new Sessions();

        List<Session> lstSessions = new List<Session>();

        lstSessions.Add(session1);
        lstSessions.Add(session2);

        sessions.SessionCollection = lstSessions;

        SourceClass src = new SourceClass();
        src.SourceSessions = sessions;

        DestinationClass dest = new DestinationClass();

        Sessions sessionsCopy = new Sessions();
        sessionsCopy = src.SourceSessions;

        Mapper.Map(sessionsCopy,dest);

        MessageBox.Show(dest.Sessions[0].ToString());

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There's two possible ways of doing this.  The first is simply to use LINQ.  If `src` is an instance of `SourceClass`:

```
var dest = new DestinationClass
{
    Sessions = src.SourceSessions.SessionCollection.Select(s => s.SessionInfo).ToList()
};
```

If you want to go theAutomapper route, you could tell Automapper to use the above expression when mapping the object:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SourceClass, DestinationClass>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Sessions, o => o.MapFrom(sess => sess.SourceSessions.SessionCollection.Select(s => s.SessionInfo)));
```

**UPDATE:**

Here's a unit test to validate the mapping:

```
var src = new SourceClass
{
    SourceSessions = new Sessions
    {
        SessionCollection = new List<Session>
        {
            new Session
            {
                SessionInfo = new DateTime(2012, 1, 2),
            },
            new Session
            {
                SessionInfo = new DateTime(2014, 5, 6)
            }
        }
    }
};

Mapper.CreateMap<SourceClass, DestinationClass>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Sessions, o => o.MapFrom(sess => sess.SourceSessions.SessionCollection.Select(s => s.SessionInfo)));
Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

var dest = Mapper.Map<SourceClass, DestinationClass>(src);
Assert.AreEqual(2, dest.Sessions.Count);
Assert.IsTrue(dest.Sessions.Contains(new DateTime(2012, 1, 2)));
Assert.IsTrue(dest.Sessions.Contains(new DateTime(2014, 5, 6)));
```

Comment: Hi Patrick.. Thanks for your help. However I do understand your approach yet there is a problem that i encountered with it. This one do not resolve the mapping as the DestinationClass is List<dateTime> where the SessionInfo from Session object is simply DateTime.

Comment: According to your original post, DestinationClass is a class that contains a List<DateTime>, it is not itself a List<DateTime>.  Is the original class definition not accurate?  If you'd like, I can post a unit test using your original source and destination class definitions to show both the LINQ approach and the Automapper approach work as described in my answer.

Comment: Its correct that DestinationClass contains List<DateTime> and it is exactly as per the classes I showed in original query. Also I used mapping as you shown but I am getting the error on var dest = Mapper.Map<SourceClass, DestinationClass>(src);.

Comment: The concern that I have is to do with  Mapper.CreateMap<SourceClass, DestinationClass>()
                .ForMember(d => d.Sessions, o => o.MapFrom(sess => sess.SourceSessions.SessionCollection.Select(s => s.SessionInfo)));. It may be that sess.SourceSessions.SessionCollection.Select(s => s.SessionInfo)) is referring to one instance of DateTime where the destination class contains the list of datetime. please correct me if I am wrong. I am still trying to change it so sess.SourceSessions.SessionCollection.Select(s => s.SessionInfo)) line could return the list of SessionInfo.

Comment: Updated answer with a unit test that validates the mapping.  Let me know if this doesn't work for you.

Comment: The problem is the way AutoMapper's Map method is called:

Mapper.Map(sessionsCopy,dest); // fails

var dest = Mapper.Map<SourceClass, DestinationClass>(src); // works